# Python 3 .lower() function returning error

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw

I am making a Reddit bot (pretty much irrelevant.), and I am trying to check if the text: `[submission]` is in the title of any submission in a Subreddit.

Here is my code: (I have  all of the tokens and secrets and things already set, along with a subreddit.)

```py
for submission in reddit.subreddit("MinecraftCommandJam").new():
    lowercaseT = str(submission.title()).lower()
    if '[submission]' in lowercaseT:
        print(submission.title)
```

But when I run the code, this error occurs (python 3)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hjdom\reddit_bot_mcj\reddit_bot.py", line 42, in <module>
    lowercaseT = str(submission.title()).lower()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\hjdom\reddit_bot_mcj>
```

Comment: Always use a good linter with Python. You can likely build it into your IDE/editor.

Comment: Are you sure that `submission.title()` is returning a string? Could there be an instance where it is returning an object or null value?

Comment: @DogEatDog that wouldn't cause a problem.  @Carcigenicate has nailed it -- he has created a variable called `str` somewhere in his code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: Ha, I assumed `submission` was a string, and that `title` was a method. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, always provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can copy-paste-tweak your code and help you.

By googling a bit, I found that [`praw.models.Submission`](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/submission.html#praw.models.Submission) objects have a `.title` attribute, a `str`. So the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` is not caused by calling `.lower()`, but by `submission.title()` instead.

Since `submission.title` is already a `str`, this should work:

```py
for submission in reddit.subreddit("MinecraftCommandJam").new():
    lowercaseT = submission.title.lower()
    if '[submission]' in lowercaseT:
        print(submission.title)
```

Comment: this is my current code:
```
for submission in reddit.subreddit("MinecraftCommandJam").new():
    lowercaseT = submission.title().lower()
    if '[submission]' in lowercaseT:
        print(submission.title)
```
yet it still returns this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hjdom\reddit_bot_mcj\reddit_bot.py", line 42, in <module>
    lowercaseT = submission.title().lower()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\hjdom\reddit_bot_mcj>

Comment: Take a look at my answer: you have `submission.title().lower()`, whereas I have `submission.title.lower()`. The problem is that `submission.title` is a string, so `submission.title()` raises an error since strings are not callable.